# SQL Server : query grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, minimum

I have some queries in SQL Server. I have two tables

1. keyword_text
2. Keyword_relate

Columns in `keyword_text`:

1. key_id
2. keywords

Columns in `keyword_relate`:

1. key_id
2. product_id
3. score
4. status

Sample data for `keyword_text`:

```
----|----------
1   | Pencil
2   | Pen
3   | Books
```

Sample data for `keyword_relate`:

```
----------------------------
Sno| Product | SCore|status
---------------------------
1  | 124     | 2    | 1
1  | 125     | 3    | 1
2  | 124     | 3    | 1
2  | 125     | 2    | 1
```

From this I want to get the `product_id`, grouped by keywords and which have maximum score

Comment: What's your query look like?

Comment: Is `key_id` of first table `Sno` in second table?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that `key_id` of first table is `Sno` in second table. You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Product AS ProductID, Score As MaxScore,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY kt.key_id ORDER BY Score DESC)
    FROM  keyword_text kt INNER JOIN keyword_relate kr
    ON kt.key_id = kr.Sno
)
SELECT ProductID, MaxScore
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```